# Open route service produces unexpected result (error)

Tags: python, api, openrouteservice

I expected that open route service with give me the coordinates of the path from start to the end point but instead i got an error as **Access to this API has been disallowed**. Can someone please help me, with what i am doing wrong ?

```
import openrouteservice as ors 
import os
import folium

API_KEY = os.environ['api_key']

client = ors.Client(key=API_KEY)

coordinates = [[-86.781247, 36.163532], [-80.191850, 25.771645]]

# directions
route = client.directions(coordinates=coordinates,
                          profile='driving-car',
                          format='geojson')

# map
map_directions = folium.Map(location=[33.77, -84.37], zoom_start=5)

# add geojson to map
folium.GeoJson(route, name='route').add_to(map_directions)

# add layer control to map (allows layer to be turned on or off)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_directions)

# display map
map_directions._repr_html_()
```

*This is the error, I got:*

```
raise exceptions.ApiError(
openrouteservice.exceptions.ApiError: 403 ({'error': 'Access to this API has been disallowed'})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error-code came up right after I started loading the API key as an environment variable. Turns out, the value loaded from `os.environ` contained quotations on either end of the string because I mistakenly included them in my `.env` file.

This might not be your case, so -- generally speaking -- try to assert that the API key you load from `os.environ` is exactly what's given to you by Openrouteservice.

I hope this helps.